# JS insert two successive text Node in a span misbehave when not on debugging mode

Tags: javascript

I am developing a characters toolbar (a div with  buttons).
when the user click a character it should be inserted in a content editable span at its current cursor position.
It works fine for the first inserted character, but when trying to insert directly the second character, it is inserted in the old caret position.
Function works fine when I click on the span( or write from keyboard  or even if a debugger is attached or when I set an `alert()` )then insert the second character.

I've tried the `setTimeout` functionality but it didn't help.

My code is as follows:

```js
function Toolbar_Click(event) {

  $('#mySpan').focus();

  M_InsertTextATCaret(character);

}


function M_InsertTextATCaret(text) {

  var retVal = true;

  try {

    var range = M_GetRange();
    if (range) {

      var textNode = M_GetTextNode(text);

      range.insertNode(textNode);

    }

  } catch (e) {
    retVal = false
  };

  return retVal;
}

function M_GetTextNode(text) {

  var retVal = M_CreateTextNode(text, "p");

  return retVal;
}

/// <summary>
/// Create Text Node from copied text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">the  text</param>
/// <param name="HtmlTagName">the  parent Node tag Name</param>
function M_CreateTextNode(text, HtmlTagName) {
  var retVal = document.createDocumentFragment();

  var p = document.createElement(HtmlTagName);
  $(p).html(text);

  var child;

  while ((child = p.firstChild)) {
    retVal.appendChild(child);
  }

  return retVal;
}

/// <summary>
/// return selection range
/// </summary>
function M_GetRange() {
  var retVal;

  if (w3) {
    retVal = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  } else if (ie) {
    retVal = document.selection.createRange();
  }

  return retVal;
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following solved the problem.

```
range.collapse(false);
```